# What is the quickest way to get to the Phone app's favorites list?

Tags: iphone, ios

I can no longer double-tap the home button to get to the iPhone's Phone apps' favorites list.

I'm looking for an alternative method to quickly access the favorites list, possibly using gestures?

Comment: Are you referring to [the multi-tasking bar](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4211)?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer (@Paul) seems confusing, but I somewhat get what he is saying. Basically, closing the Phone app after selecting the Favorites tab at the bottom of the screen, and then re-opening the app will return you to the Favorites tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's still there. Just open the Phone app, leave it, open, and then double-tap the home button the open the phone app.

Answer (score 0):

If you jailbreak your phone, you can download Activator and create a triple-click action to show your favorites.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a little off topic, however, you could have a look at my app [phonetrait](http://apps.paulsteinhilber.de/phonetrait). This app tries to make it easier and faster to place calls.

The apps shows your contacts ordered by how often and how recently they are called, which creates an dynamic 'favorites' list.

Comment: While related, this doesn't address the OP's question; the app doesn't appear to be driven by the Favorites list in the Phone app, but by the most-frequently-called numbers, for starters.

Comment: @DanJ Unfortunately there is at the moment no from Apple supported way to programmatically read out the phones favorites list. However the app allows to compile a dynamic 'favorites' list to facilitate contacting people.